# How to control \chapter text related to \tableofcontents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, header-footer, chapters

How can I control `\chapter` text associated with `\tableofcontents`

1. How to change the font size of `\chapter{text}` in TOC page.
2. How to restrict TOC pages to ONE. (Two pages are coming as default).
3. At the beginning of the chapter, text is coming in very big size font.
   How can I control it.
4. Chapter text is coming immediately after page number. I want to introduce space between page number and chapter text. How can I do it.
5. How can I change the page number position.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{(Chapter One)}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Right now, we know neither your document class nor what (if any) ToC-related packages you use.

Comment: You have a number of questions here. It might be better if you separate them out into one per question posted.

Comment: What do you mean in 2? Do you have, say (toc)(blank page)(start of a chapter)? If this is what you mean, you should look into the openleft/openright/openany options (to the document class). They determine whether a new chapter can start on a left (verso) or right (recto) page, or on both. The default setting is openright, which means that your ToC appears on one page, and then the first chapter cannot appear before page 3, causing a blank page to be inserted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Joseph said, 5 questions packed into 1 question is a bit difficult to handle. Nevertheless, here are 5 points for you to continue:

1. [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) allows to fine-tune TOC entries.
2. You could use a `minipage` environment for the TOC. If the TOC doesn't cover much more than one page, you could use `\enlargethispage` or its starred version `\enlargethispage*` which tries to squeeze, such as

   `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}}`
3. I guess you mean the chapter heading. You could use [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) to adjust it.
4. Chapter text after page number? Perhaps do you mean after chapter number? Also here, `titlesec` would help.
5. You could use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or [`scrpage2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) (of KOMA-Script) to modify page header and footer, this way also adjusting the page number position. To change the margins, use [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) or [`typearea`](http://ctan.org/pkg/typearea).

Perhaps the documentation of the mentioned packages already helps in working that out. If not, consider to post a separate question for any open problem. This site works best in the way: one concrete question - one or more answers to it.